# PHP Loop a functions parameter from 1 to 10

Tags: php, loops

I have a function called calculate. And inside the calculate function I have a paramater next to it

```
function calculate($id){
..
}
```

What I'm trying to figure out how to do is make a loop which will start the loop and the function calculate will start with the ($id) next to it from 1 to 10. So it does the same thing 10 times with the id set to 1 then 2 then 3 and so on to 10.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try using `range`

```
  function calculate($id){
     //other statements
     // return ;
    } 

 foreach (range(0, 10) as $id) {
    calculate($id);
 }
```

Comment: @Mark Amery Thanks for pointing out. I have edited. :)

Comment: Thanks for fixing it :D